# Filtering List using CAML query and Binding it to dropdown in C#

Tags: development, filter

I have the following code which retrieves all items from list "Employee Info" and bind it to Dropdown list EmployeeDD.

```
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SPSite mySite = SPContext.Current.Site;
                SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb();

                SPList list = myWeb.Lists["Employee Info"];
                DataTable DTable_List = list.Items.GetDataTable();
                DTable_List.TableName = "Table1";
                ds.Tables.Add(DTable_List);

                EmployeeDD.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"];
                EmployeeDD.DataTextField = "Title";
                EmployeeDD.DataValueField = "Title";

                EmployeeDD.DataBind();
                EmployeeDD.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
```

it displays all the Employees in a list.Now how do I filter the Employees based on Current logged in user and just show that user in dropdown list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To query any person or group  field against logged in user  you can use `**<UserID/>**`   tag in Value.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            SPList list = myWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Employee Info");
                            if (list != null)
                            {
                                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                                query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FieldToCompare' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Integer' ><UserID/></Value></Eq></Where>";
                                query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>";
                                query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
                                SPListItemCollection itemColl = list.GetItems(query);
                                if (itemColl != null)
                                {
                                    EmployeeDD.DataSource = itemColl;
                                    EmployeeDD.DataBind();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am going to fill DropdownList 'ddEmp' with all the values present in the List 'EmpInfo' where userID is equal to current userId.

```
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)

    {

    using(SPSite siteColl= new SPSite("http://hjkdh.com"));

      {
        using(SPWeb web1=siteColl.OpenWeb());

         {


             List mylist= mywb.List("EmployeeInfo");

             ListItemCollection itemslist=new ListItemCollection();

             CamlQuery query=new CamlQuery();
             query="";

             itemslist=mylist.GetItems(query);

             ddEmp.DataSource=itemsList;
             ddEmp.DataBind();

          }

      }


    }  

}
```